# IIS Media Services on Windows 10

Tags: iis, installation, windows-media-services

Has anyone managed to get IIS media services to install on Windows 10? When I try it tells me I need IIS 7.0 or higher. I have version 10.0.10240.16384 installed so it seems it is not detecting the version correctly. I am guessing there is a registry hack somewhere that will get it to install - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Media Services are shipped out of band after each server OS release and have been quiet for a long while after Azure Media Services launches.

Comment: OK, so why can I not run Media Services 4.1 with IIS 10? Surely IIS 10 is a version more recent that IIS 7.0 so the error is rubbish. I am wondering if it is a genuine problem or just some half-arsed version checking from Microsoft that I can work around. I note that IIS really has _nothing_ to do with the OS version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try this:

Firstly closed IIS Manager, then changed the IIS MajorVersion in the registry to 9, installed urlrewrite from the MSI with no problems and changed the registry version back to 10.

Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp

Value: MajorVersion

refer to:
https://forums.iis.net/t/1227944.aspx?IIS+Media+Service+4+1+failed+to+install+on+Windows10+because+it+can+t+recognize+it+is+IIS7+or+above

Comment: Brilliant, that worked, many thanks. You did well to find anything on the IIS forums - I searched there and failed to find anything!

Answer (score 0):

This is a more detailed description of the registry "hack" needed to fool the installer so as to install on Windows 10:

1. Open Regedit > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp
2. Edit "MajorVersion" and set the "DECIMAL" value to 9
3. Hit F5 while in Regedit
4. Now go install the ReWrite 2.0 module.
5. Change the "MajorVersion" back to "DECIMAL" value of 10
6. Hit F5 while in Regedit
7. Close Regedit

This came from: https://forums.iis.net/t/1223556.aspx